# Getting Length of Object in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to set up an array in jQuery and I then need to do a for loop on it. But it seems that I cant use an associative array for some reason?

```
var items = new Array();
items['foo'] = 123456;
items['bar'] = 789012;
items['baz'] = 345678;
items['bat'] = 901234;
alert(items.length);
```

This is just a test, but it return 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't make `associative array` in JavaScript like what you want, instead  you can use **[Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)**.

For example:

```
var items = {
  foo : 123456,
  bar : 789012,
  baz : 345678,
  bat : 901234
}
```

And to calculate the length you can do:

```
var getObjectSize = function(obj) {
    var len = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) len++;
    }
    return len;
};
```

Use: `getObjectSize(items); // output: 4`

For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array).

Another one is:

```
Object.keys(items).length;
```

#### *But not supported by all browsers.*

Comment: JavaScript objects are also associative arrays. I'm sure of it, I use this flexibility all the time.

Comment: Yep, check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array

Comment: Technically, no -- JavaScript associative arrays are objects that happen to behave like associative arrays. But as I've said on this subject before, if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, just call it a duck.

Comment: @Diego: In languages that don't thoroughly conflate "array" and "dictionary" (i'm looking at you, PHP!), an "array" is a sequence of contiguous elements indexed by number and a "dictionary" is a key->value map.  JS's only likeness between them is that "array" indexes are object properties, and an object is a "dictionary".  Anything that's not numeric is not an array element; it's an object property.

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = new Array();
items['foo'] = 123456;
```

The problem lies in the very first line. You believe that you are adding an item to the array at the index `foo`, but you are actually adding a property to the `items` variable with a key `foo` and value `123456`. If you were to type `items.foo` it would give you back your `123456`.

The problem with this approach is that adding a property to an array does not magically increase it's length.

If you want to have non-numeric indexes, you need to use an object instead of an array:

```
var items = {
    foo: 123456,
    bar: 789012,
    baz: 345678,
    bat: 901234
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be to set up two different arrays, which you construct in parallel:

```
var items = [], items2 = [];
items.push('foo');
items2.push(123456);
// etc.
alert(items2.length);​
```

The efficiency of this approach depends on how you'll use it. If you're only going to loop through the list of items and do something to each of them, this approach may be more efficient. But if you need to *use* it like an associative array (`items['foo']`), then you're better off building an object.

Comment: `items = items2 = []` points `items` and `items2` at the exact same array, making the length double what it should be due to its having both the keys and values.

Comment: Whoops, I was mixing my JavaScript and PHP and creating something entirely new in the process. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The .length property returns the *highest numerical index of the array*. Thus, in your case, there is no numerical index and it returns 0. Try

```
items[98] = "something";
```

items.length will be 98..! Use the .length property with caution, and if you also want to count the non-numerical indici, loop over the Object (an Array is also an Object) and count its ownProperties.